# Discord py - Same bot on different servers

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

**I am currently building a bot for multiple servers. The goal is to store different IDs for different servers in one json file.**

The only problem is that I don't know how to check which server the bot is currently on and then use this information to use the correct IDs.

I already created a json file and loaded it into my code, but now I don't know how to load and use the correct IDs from it.

My json file looks like this at the moment:

```json
{

    "token": 123,
    "server1": [
        {
            "ownerid": 123,
            "memberid": 123,
            "IDs" : [
                {
                    "messageid": 123,
                    "roleid": 123
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

    "server2": [
        {
            "ownerid": 123,
            "memberid": 123
        }
    ]
}
```

**How can I check which server the bot is currently on?
Does json even do that or do I need something else?**

I really cant find any tutorial how to use the same bot on several servers??
Can you guys give me any examples?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be storing the ID of the guild once it joins (and maybe deleting it when it lefts).

As some guidelines, to get the id of each guild, something like this would work:

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
   id = guild.id
```

In the case that you have the creation of the JSON in another function or your bot is already running on multiple servers and you want to know which `guilds` is he currently in, you could iterate the `client.guilds` attribute:

```
for guild in self.client.guilds:
   id = guild.id
   # Add id to JSON
```

Comment: And can I save the individual IDs for a certain server in json? How do I have to import the json then? Normal with an ``open with`` and then the call or is there something special?

Comment: In my example it was only to store the `guild id`, if you want to store other ids within that just iterate for example `for member.id in guild.members` or `for role.id in guild.roles`.  [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library can help you with dumping the info into your files.